# How to access the application(exposed on port 7600) from docker container inside a container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a Jenkins docker container running on a ec2(Amazon linux AMI) and i am able to access the jenkins container with IP:PORT on web browser.

```
[@~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                             NAMES
74db49830336        jenkins_1             "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   jenkins_1
```

I have created a job which will create container inside Jenkins container and which is exposed on port 7600

```
jenkins@74db49830336:/# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                              NAMES
b4527d9ef554        cloudwaveapp_10     "runaceserver"      56 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes       0.0.0.0:7600->7600/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7800->7800/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7843->7843/tcp, 9483/tcp   cloudwave1
```

i have added(exposed) all the ports in EC2 Instance inbound rules

Issue:- I am not able to access the IP:7600 on web browser.

Comment: Your outer container does not expose port 7600. Theoretically if you ran a web browser inside your outer container, you would be able to access IP:7600 in it.

Comment: @MTCoaster- I have exposed the port on ec2 instance  inbound rules- 7600.... want to know how i can expose the port in outer container?

Comment: (*MTCoster) That doesn't change the fact that your Jenkins container doesn't expose port 7600 though

Comment: how i can check the port is exposed to outside world in outercontainer?

Comment: The `PORTS` column in the output of `docker ps`: `50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp` does not include the required `0.0.0.0:7600->7600/tcp` mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map this port you need -p 7600:7600 when starting Jenkins container. So you kind of mapping the inside ports to outer system (think of onion).
Anyway - this is bad idea to run container in container. You can achieve the same when having shared volumes/network for communication. Container in container provide bigger mental load and you need to mount extra devices to the first Jenkins container.